# fe_sendauth: no password supplied when creating database

Tags: docker

I am in the process of dockerizing our Ruby on rails apps.  One of them is throwing the following error when I run docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:create

```
Starting sapi_db_1 ... done
[WARNING] The git gem requires git 1.6.0.0 or later, but only found 
2.1.4. You should probably upgrade.
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I am confirmed the config files are working as I have used them 3 times previously with oher apps.

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN gem install bundler
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

ADD . /app
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/sapi
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
       DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
```

My database.yml file

```
 default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
 <<: *default
     database: app_development
```

How can I resolve this?  I have already confirmed that the config files work by carrying the process out on other apps.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by changing the .env file